# Cancelation token created with promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, cancellation

I have a function and I want to use it and understand

The hard part for me is token.promise and cancelation function. Can someone describe how the function below works ?

```
export function createCancelToken () {
  const token = {}
  let cancel
  token.promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    // The cancelation function
    cancel = reason => {
      // The reason can be checked synchronously to see if the promise is canceled
      token.reason = reason
      resolve(reason)
    }
  })

  return [token, cancel]
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this code that you did not write yourself?

Comment: I feel like a `cancellationToken` should `reject()` instead of `resolve()` if it is to be semantically accurate... just a nitpick though.

Answer (score 0):

token is an object which has `token.promise` and, potentially at some point in the future, `token.reason` on it.

`token.promise` is an actual promise, with methods `.then` and `.catch`. Apparently `.then` will be called after the promise is cancelled, with the `reason` as the only argument.

So you call the function `let arr = createCancelToken()` and you get the token and cancel objects out of it, `let token = arr[0]; let cancel = arr[1]`. At some later time you can call `cancel('no reason');` at which `token.promise.then(reason => {})` will run, with `reason` being 'no reason'